# Line-integration along a parametrized curve

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, riemann-surfaces, riemann-integration

Exercise:
$\int_{\alpha}{( x^2 + y^2 )}d\alpha$ where $\alpha$ is the curve parameterized by $x=a(\cos(t)+ t\sin(t))$, $y=a(\sin(t)-t\cos(t))$ (correction by DonAntonio's) with $t \in [0,2\pi]$ where $a>0$

**Proof**

$M=\int_{\alpha}{( x^2 + y^2 )}d\alpha$

$M=\int_{0}^{2\pi}{a^2 \cos(t)^2 + a^2 t^2\sin(t)^2 + a^2 \sin(t)^2 + a^2 t^2\cos(t)^2}$ $dt$ ??? (it's that I have)

**Solution**

$M=16\pi^2(1+2\pi^2)$

*Have some idea how to solve this integral of line, some hint to find the solution???*

**Example**

If the circumference is $x^2+y^2=ax$ in the form $(x-a/2)^2 + y^2 = a^2/4$
where $C$ is parameterized by $x=(a/2)+(a/2)\cos(t)$ and $y=(a/2)\sin(t)$ with $(0\leq t\leq 2\pi)$

That mode

$\sigma'(t)=(-a\sin(t/2),a\cos(t/2))$ then $|\sigma'(t)|=a/2$

Then

$M=\int_{C}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}ds=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{a^2/2 (1+\cos(t)a/2)}dt$

$...$

$M=\frac{a^2}{2}\cdot 2(1-\cos(t))^{1/2}|_{0}^{2\pi}=0$

Comment: Is the $d\alpha$ $ds$ as you integrate with respect to arc length $s$?

Comment: In the example that i put in the publication the change of $ds$ to $dt$ is given, Now I do not know how events occurred in $M$

Comment: Well don't forget that cosx^2+sinx^2=1; you have it twice there

Comment: You must be integrating wrt arc length $\;ds\;$, otherwise I cannot understand the notation $\;(x^2+y^2)d\alpha\;$ ...and even then this integral looks really horrible. A little change in the sign of the second summand in $\;y(t)\;$ would help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that there is a typo (see also DonAntonio's comment) and the parametrized curve $\alpha$ should be 
$$x:=a(\cos(t)+t\sin(t)),\quad y=a(\sin(t)-t\cos(t))$$
for $t\in [0,2\pi]$. Then
$$x^2+y^2=a^2(1+t^2)\quad\mbox{and}\quad ds=\sqrt{(x'(t))^2+(y'(t))^2}=at.$$
Therefore
$$\int_{\alpha}{( x^2 + y^2 )}ds=a^3\int_{0}^{2\pi}(1+t^2)t dt=2a^3\pi^2(1+2\pi^2).$$

Comment: Ah, exactly what I commented...and yet the OP did **not** change his question nor even addressed the comment....

Comment: Ok, I have it, now I going to analyze this answer and studied more examples, thanks